# Show activity on ringing screen when device is password protected

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-windowmanager

I am trying to develop an android application which will show the caller's information on call received. My code works fine. but when the device is password protected and then call is received the user has to first enter the password and then everything works fine. So how to make my custom screen visible to user even when the device is locked ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution.
Silly though.
Services run in background and need not check the phone is locked or not.
So what i did that i showed the window manager in the service.
Cheers !

Comment: Are you able to capture click events on your views using WindowManager?